# Why does my CNN keras model stagnates its accuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So my question as the title suggests is about my model stagnating at around 0.33 accuracy.

My model is made by cnn's and 3 dense layers and it goes as follow:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(580, 360, 1), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())  # Flattening the 2D arrays for fully connected layers

model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(364, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(266, activation='softmax'))
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.00001) # I've tried with default as well as with bigger lr
model.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 
history = model.fit(trainDataset, epochs=40)
```

I've tried with default as well as with bigger learning rate. I've tried with different optimizers as well as different strides on `Conv2D` and also less/more `Conv2D`. I believe that this metrics and loss functions should be the most appropriate although i'm not sure.

This is how it ends:

```
205/209 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3203 - accuracy: 0.3491
206/209 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3203 - accuracy: 0.3491
207/209 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3203 - accuracy: 0.3491
208/209 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3202 - accuracy: 0.3490
209/209 [==============================] - 52s 248ms/step - loss: 2.3193 - accuracy: 0.3491
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Also, how can i find the best suitable `batch_size` as well as the best `kernel_size`/`strides`?

Thanks in advance!

Versions:

Keras:2.3.1 
Tensorflow-GPU:2.0.0 
CUDA:10.1
Python:3.7

Comment: Did you try data augmentation? ImageDataGenerator of keras is the most simple way to do that

Comment: I am guessing that may be data was not normalized. Can you check it once. Another thing I noticed was that you are using dropout from the start. Please let the model learn and add dropout later part of the model.

Comment: So i did diminish the number of dropouts and only added them to the Dense layers and now it seems to be working fine! Thanks!